# Bonding Two Cationic Hydrogen Isotopes (protium) yields H2 or He?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, subatomic

If you have two hydrogen atoms. And they are the isotope form "Protium" (1 neutron removed) and they are also cationized +1 (1 electron removed) then you have (in a sense) a single proton (two of them actually).

---

1) Are these protons just subatomic particles now (i.e. protons)? Or are they still "Atoms" consisting of only a proton?

2) If you were to bond them, would you have a weird cationized isotope form of H<sub>2</sub> or would you have a weird cationized isotope form of He

---

I would imagine the bond has the 2 protons close to each other, but they are not close enough to have a "strong nuclear force" and thefore are just bonded, not fused, and are technically H<sub>2</sub> and only become He when they get close enough to be classified as a Nucleus?

Comment: He$^{^2}$ is not stable - it very rapidly decays to two protons.

Comment: "and thefore are just bonded, not fused, and are technically $\mathrm{H_2}$" does not correspond to any physical reality. W/o at least one electron no bonding MO can be formed. 2 protons are fused into $\mathrm{He^2}$ or they remain just that: 2 protons...

Comment: @Gert so if you had two protiums bonded into H2 isotope (with electrons) and then you cationized it, it would just become 2 protons?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: I think you're confusing isotopes and molecules. $\mathrm{He^{2}}$ is an (unstable) isotope, obtained by *fusion* of 2 protons. $\mathrm{H_2}$ is a molecule of diprotium, obtained by chemical reaction between 2 protium *atoms*.